# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized property "onsRemoteConfig"

Tags: database, oracle

When i try to connect to the Oracle 12c RAC DB from my java client code. I get the following error . Tried disabling the 'Fan Enabled' property in middleware (Weblogic console) for the DATASource which is used .But still get the same error . Any pointers ?

```
Nov 08, 2021 11:11:34 AM oracle.simplefan.impl.FanManager configure
SEVERE: unrecognized property while configuring FanManager
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized property "onsRemoteConfig"
    at oracle.simplefan.impl.FanManager.configure(FanManager.java:71)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.HAManager.configure(HAManager.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.HAManager.<init>(HAManager.java:122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.HAManager.getInstance(HAManager.java:126)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.HAManager.enableHAIfNecessary(HAManager.java:725)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:713)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be having multiple versions of ojdbc*.jar in classpath . After removing the all but one , i the issue is resolved.